# Locked Windmill Key

Tags: the-witcher-3

In white orchard there is a windmill near a bandit camp. The door to the windmill is locked and I cannot find the key.

Where is this key?

Comment: I wondered this too. It drove me especially nuts since I kept thinking I had to get in there for a quest (turns out, I really needed to go underneath the house)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around at multiple forums and such, people have come to the conclusion that you just can't open the door. This has been deduced mostly by the fact that several people can't find it, as well as the fact that there are no windows of any sort to look into the building.

Traditionally (this isn't every case) when you can't see inside of a building in any way, there's no way inside.

Edit: Someone had said they got in when they picked the Master Key as their starting gift, but that has since been removed.

It's possible that this will be used in DLC some day and that's why the door is interactable, but as of right now no one has figured out how to get in.

Comment: What starting gift? That sounds like Dark Souls, not Witcher 3.